# save an int/boolean value after app is closed

Tags: android

How do I save an int/boolean value after the app is closed so that when I start the app the int value will go to a textview like a personal record in a game?

```
int personalRecord = 30;
```

Comment: http://android4yourfuture.blogspot.gr/2012/10/android-shared-preferences-tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the value to SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To save:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit(); 
editor.putInt("personalRecord", 30);
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve:

```
mPreferences.getInt("personalRecord", defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SharedPreferences`.
    Try this code.

```
        int count = 2;
        boolean bool = true;
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("int", count);
        editor.putBoolean("bool", bool);
        editor.commit();
```

for retriving value from `SharedPreferences`

```
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
        int count = preferences.getInt("int",0);
        boolean bool = preferences.getBoolean("bool",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended Shared Preferences:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html